# How many shards is facebook's user table partitioned across?

Tags: database, mongodb, facebook, nosql, sharding

`"Shard Manager manages tens of millions of shards hosted on hundreds of thousands of servers across hundreds of applications in production."`

https://engineering.fb.com/2020/08/24/production-engineering/scaling-services-with-shard-manager/

If the above is true, then suppose that facebook has 3 billion users and this table is partitioned across 10 million shards, as the document suggests, then each table / shard only contains 300 rows / users?

And so whenever a query that requires returning an arbitrary list of users is made to the database, potentially 100s of thousands of servers go to work in parallel to fetch this list?

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Interesting question, I'd be interested to know the answer too. Also, your display name and profile are highly informative.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is cross-posted at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/329697/how-many-shards-is-facebooks-user-table-partitioned-across where it has a useful answer.